# Ruby on Rails - use where with array of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my Post object has post_categories array

```
Post.post_categories = []
```

For my all Post object i need to filter posts by post_categories which include 1

like this

```
Post.all.where :post_categories.include? 1
```

how can i do

these are models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizes
  has_many :post_categories, :through=>:categorizes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_categories
end

class PostCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizes
  has_many :posts, :through=>:categorizes
end

class Categorize < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :post_category
end
```

Comment: Just show the two corresponding models.. I need to see it..

Comment: Can you show me what I asked.. I think I can help you there.. But before need to check how you define the associations...

Comment: Try `Post.joins(:categorizes).where("categorizes.id in (?)", 1)`...

Comment: it is working with categories id. i need to filter by post_category_id
for example if i have two Post, post1.post_categories = [1,2,3] and post2.post_categories = [1,4] and if i filter with 4 only post2 show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a join and filter on the ID field of the joined table:
`Post.joins(:post_categories).where('post_categories.id' => 1)`